# When using the Windows Automated Installation Kit do I need install.wim?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sysprep, waik

I've prepared an unattended install answer file using the Windows Automated Installation Kit (WAIK) so I can `sysprep` a Windows 2008 image. This obviously required `install.wim` from the Windows source DVD for the purposes of creating a catalogue.

Do I need to have the `install.wim` file on the image that is being sysprep'd or can sysprep run without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the time to try this, on the machine being sysprep'd there is no need to copy the `install.wim` file. All that's needed is the answer file.